# How to stop automatic freshclam execution

Tags: upgrade, updates, services, process, clamav

I have the latest version of `freshclam` and `clamav` installed, and in the past (when I had Ubuntu 14.10) it has only run `freshclam` automatically a few times a day, but has not been running all the time. Now what I am finding though that if I go to Terminal and execute:

```
sudo freshclam
```

That I get:

```
ERROR: /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log is locked by another process
ERROR: Problem with internal logger (UpdateLogFile = /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log).
```

And then the only way to be able to manually run that command is to kill the `freshclam` process, but this is time wasting, and annoying, so I would like to fully stop `freshclam` from auto updating, so that I can do manual updates.

So what I tried was to install [clamtk](https://code.google.com/p/clamtk/), and in the `Update Assistant` settings I tried to set it so that I would manually install updates, and then I clicked `Apply`, but this seemed, even after a restart, to have no impact on how `freshclam` behaved.

So really my question is, how can I get it so that `freshclam` does not automatically check for updates, or at least for it to do it a few times a day, but not always be there so that I have to kill it to run it? Or is there a way to fix `clamtk` so that it does it properly (I have got in touch with the developer of `clamtk` and he is looking into it, but does not know what the issue is)?

---

### OS Information:

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

### Package Information:

**ClamTk:**

```
clamtk:
  Installed: 5.18-1
  Candidate: 5.18-1
  Version table:
 *** 5.18-1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.15-1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe amd64 Packages
```

**ClamAV:**

```
clamav:
  Installed: 0.98.7+dfsg-0ubuntu0.15.04.1
  Candidate: 0.98.7+dfsg-0ubuntu0.15.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 0.98.7+dfsg-0ubuntu0.15.04.1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.98.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Related to https://askubuntu.com/a/1204422/231142

---

That is the `freshclam` daemon running that is causing that error message.  If you check the log, `tail -10 /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log` you will probably see updates for the freshclam as early as today.  As long as you're seeing updates, everything is working fine.  I actually don't recommend disabling it as you might forget to update later on.

If you want to change the intervals to the `freshclam` daemon, type in the following from a terminal window:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure clamav-freshclam
```

then step through the setup.  In the setup, it asks how many times a day for it to update.  It defaults to 24 (once per hour).  If you want it to update more, set it for 48 (twice per hour).  12 for once every 2 hours.

Answer (score 6):

I know this already has an accepted answer, but in my case it didn't help:
any `dpkg-reconfigure` setting `freshclam` to manual updates would result in a running daemon after rebooting, no matter what.

what did the trick for me was disabling it from `init.d` completely, with this line:

```
 sudo update-rc.d clamav-freshclam disable
```

hope this will be of help to anyone running in my same issues

Comment: The daemon will run automatically at boot, so you can append that line to the end of your `.bashrc` file. Every time you log in, the shell will execute it for you. Although, I highly suggest allowing the program to auto-update it self and instead append a line that creates a copy of the original log to let you know that it has indeed updated.