# After fresh install of clamav getting errors?

Tags: command-line

```
root@dc1:~# freshclam
ERROR: /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log is locked by another process
ERROR: Problem with internal logger (UpdateLogFile = /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log).
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop automatic freshclam execution](http://askubuntu.com/questions/636851/how-to-stop-automatic-freshclam-execution)

Answer (score 1):

Only one running instance of `freshclam` is allowed at the same time[1]. You'll see that `sudo systemctl status clamav-freshclam.service` reveals that the instance has been started by the `init` manager `systemd` which should be the default after you install `freshclam`. This is good because `freshclam` will be started regularily.

If you want to start it manually run `sudo systemctl stop clamav-freshclam` and repeat the above command.

---

[1] It might be possible to get another instance running using different prefixes for installation, configuration and log files.