# Ubuntu ClamTk unable to set a time to update antivirus signatures

Tags: clamtk

[image]

As shown in the picture above, I am able to select the scan scheduler by choosing the minutes and clicking on the bottom right + icon. However for Antivirus signatures, there is no + icon. How can I set a time to update the antivirus signatures?

Comment: My bad for not not changing the image description. It is a screenshot of my clamtk scheduler. I am unable to find how I can edit my question

Comment: You probably need to set `freshclam` to manual so that you can choose what time you want it to download at.  See:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1204422/231142

Answer (score 0):

It should actually be quite straightforward but there is a little quirk in the software.

For completeness, what you need to do first is go to Update Assistant and set `I would like to update signatures my self`.

[image]

Then click on Apply.

Go back in to the scheduler and you will be able to set the time as required for Antivirus Signatures by clicking on the + sign by the side of the Hour (and Minutes if required) then click on the green plus sign underneath.

You then have to ensure that that the green + sign is clickable (dark green) to be able to save the time. If it is not, click on the minus (-) sign to make it so (which will reset the time to 0) then go back and reset to the time required - the green + sign at the bottom of the section should be clickable this time (darker green) but will change to light green when accepted by the system.

Go back into the scheduler to check. You should see at the bottom that you have a daily scan scheduled and a daily definitions update is scheduled.

You will not need to reset the option in Update Assistant which you changed earlier. The system remembers your new choice automatically.

The first image below shows the + sign as pale green (and will not save the time). The second image below shows the + sign in light green again (but was dark green before clicking it) but will be saved on clicking Close.

A bit messy, but after much research, I have managed to get to the bottom of making it work this way.

[image]

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: I'm certain that others will find this an issue too. If this answers your question, please [accept it](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) to enable others to find the solution easily. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your help. May I also know, does clamtk show when it does the scanning and updating of antivirus signatures? Even after I have set it to 1 min and wait for a few mins, I do not see any scans or antivirus signatures being updated.

Comment: I don't think it does except as to identify the current installed version (on mine v 26032) If you scan for new versions manually, you can see the progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but my version of ClamTk doesn't have any icons that turn green so it never accepted my scheduled times, however I did put it into manual updates and that worked.

Every time I tried to set the scheduler times in Deepin 20.6 it wouldn't accept the changes, so I clicked on the + sign(s) and it worked.

[image: Pic for reference]