# Is an unknown process, downloading 1 GiB data in 30 minutes, necessarily suspicious?

Tags: networking, 18.04

After a fresh boot and login (Ubuntu 18.04), I left the computer on like this for about 30 minutes. When I came back, I saw on the LTE router display. that some process downloaded almost 1 GiB in that time.

I confirmed it with `vnstat`, but I didn't menage to find out what process has used this data.

I can't think of any application that I have, that would do this.

My questions are:

1. Can it be an innocent operating system process?
2. Is it possible to discover retroactively what process downloaded so much data? (I have only `vnstat` installed).

Comment: Does `/var/log/apt/history.log` or the output of `snap changes` show anything that could be from that time interval?

Comment: maybe snap is up to something again

Comment: history.log and snap changes of the time, are empty

Comment: If it's a fresh installed system it could be cloud-init downloading updates. For one turned off for a while, it could be unattended-upgrades. And snaps as mentioned earlier. But it's hard to know without further details. 1. Yes, it can.
2. Check /var/log/apt/history.log and /var/log/syslog

Answer (score 2):

`nethogs` enabled me to see data consumption by process name.
with `nethogs` installed, I waited for another event of "mysterious data consumption". and found out it was `freshclam` process, belongs to ClamAV.

see this question:[Freshclam is Using Lots of Mobile Data](https://askubuntu.com/q/1204417/1382495)

Comment: It's ironic you suspect a virus is on your computer when it is actually anti-virus software at work.